# How to parse tshark arguments in ShellExecute function

Tags: c++, winapi, wireshark, tshark

I want to call tshark.exe from a c++ script via ShellExecute. Is there any way to parse cmd arguments to the application?
e.g. specify output file like this

```
tshark -w output.pcap
```

Here is the code

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <shellapi.h>

int main()
{
    ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "tshark.exe", NULL, "C:\Program Files\Wireshark", SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutea fourth argument is parameters

Comment: I've read it, but I don't quite understand the syntax. How an I supposed to add -w output.pcap to this?

Comment: Code doesn't compile. Go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1889329) before moving forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 4th parameter to `ShellExecute()` passes command-line arguments to the new process, eg:

```cpp
ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "tshark.exe", "-w output.pcap", "C:\\Program Files\\Wireshark", SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
```

Though, you really should be using `CreatProcess()` instead (`ShellExecute()` is just going to call it anyway):

```cpp
STARTUPINFO si = {};
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {};

si.cb = sizeof(si);
si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
si.wShowWindow = SW_SHOWDEFAULT;

char cmd[] = "tshark.exe -w output.pcap";
if (CreateProcessA(NULL, cmd, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, "C:\\Program Files\\Wireshark", &si, &pi))
{
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
}
```

Comment: Oh, thanks. I tried it before but for some reason it didn't work. Don't know why.
Now everything is OK